# C - Fetch MySQL row to char

Tags: mysql, c

I want to fetch results from my database (MySQL) and store them in an array. I tried some things, but I have no solution.

```
    mysql_real_query(mysql, query, strlen(query));
    mysql_res = mysql_store_result(mysql);
    rows_number = (unsigned long) mysql_num_rows (mysql_res);
    printf ("Number of Rows: %lu\n\n", rows_number);

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row (mysql_res)) != NULL) {
    for (i = 0;  i < mysql_num_fields(mysql_res);  i ++)
    printf ("%s ",row[i]); //this is printed like it should be.
    printf("\n");

    char *val = row[i]; //should save it to an char
    printf("%s",val);
```

But if I start the program, the output is: (only extract!)
This is what is send by printf ("%s ",row[i]); :

```
1 1 1 0006
```

And this is printed form char val:

```
</alias>
<alias>windows-1256</alias>
<collation name="cp1256_bin"        id="67" order="Binary"  flag="binary"/>
<collation name="cp1256_general_ci" id="57" order="Arabic"  flag="primary">
<order>Arabic</order>
<order>Persian</order>
<order>Pakistani</order>
<order>Urdu</order>
</collation>
</charset>
```

So what is wrong?
Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is being used outside the bounds of the for loop:

Instead of :

```
 for (i = 0;  i < mysql_num_fields(mysql_res);  i ++)
     printf ("%s ",row[i]); //this is printed like it should be.
```

You probably meant this:

```
 for (i = 0;  i < mysql_num_fields(mysql_res);  i ++)
 {
    printf ("%s ",row[i]); //this is printed like it should be.
    printf("\n");

    char *val = row[i]; //should save it to an char
    printf("%s",val);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you indent the code properly, you can see the problem

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row (mysql_res)) != NULL) {
    for (i = 0;  i < mysql_num_fields(mysql_res);  i ++)
        printf ("%s ",row[i]); //this is printed like it should be.
    printf("\n");

    char *val = row[i]; //should save it to an char
    printf("%s",val);
```

The for loop is already finished, when you assign

```
char *val = row[i];
```

So, this is a classic off by one error.